# Open ViewController With SWReveal Gesture from AppDelegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiviewcontroller, swrevealviewcontroller

I am developing an iOS app and using storyboards. In my storyboard, I had set a SWRevealViewcontroller and it works fine.

Now i have a new requirement, and i need to present a viewcontroller, which is an option from the rear_vc in the reveal from my appdelegate, after receive a push notification.

In appdelegate i'm using the next method to instantiate and show the view controller

```
- (void)showViewController {

   UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
   TheViewController *vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"vc"];
   [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
   [self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:NULL];

}
```

So, since the viewcontroller is an option from the rear viewcontroller, i need to add gesture recognizer to display menu using

```
  [self.view addGestureRecognizer:self.revealViewController.panGestureRecognizer];
  [self.view addGestureRecognizer:self.revealViewController.tapGestureRecognizer];
```

This is where i have the problem, because self.revealViewController is nil, and the app crashes in this lines, because segue is not coming directly from the rear viewcontroller.

In rear viewcontroller prepare for segue method we need to add this lines

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    if ( [segue isKindOfClass: [SWRevealViewControllerSegue class]] ) {

        SWRevealViewControllerSegue *swSegue = (SWRevealViewControllerSegue*) segue;

        swSegue.performBlock = ^(SWRevealViewControllerSegue* rvc_segue,   UIViewController* svc, UIViewController* dvc) {

        UINavigationController* navController = (UINavigationController*)self.revealViewController.frontViewController;
        [navController setViewControllers: @[dvc] animated: NO ];
        [self.revealViewController setFrontViewPosition: FrontViewPositionLeft animated: YES];
        };
    }
}
```

But from appdelegate i can't do that, how can achieve this ?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried making the rootViewController the rear controller, and then presenting the main view controller from that one?

Comment: Yes i tried, but since front vc is not instantiated, i can't perform segues or present viewcontrollers with the menu pan ant tap gestures without crashing